# Bash Scripting for opening ssh, python shell and python commands

Tags: command-line, bash, python-2.7

I'm writing a script that opens ssh, connects to django, gets data from the app using python commands from the python script ***myscript.py***. However the current code doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -hold -e ssh server python /srv/django/manage.py shell execfile ./myscript
```

With this, I get a command error: `Command doesn't accept any arguments`

I also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e ssh server python /srv/django/manage.py shell execfile('./myscript.py')
```

but got a syntax error:

> line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to put the all command into quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -hold -e ssh server "python /srv/django/manage.py shell execfile ./myscript.py"
```

it should solve your problem.

Comment: the xterminal just disappears after i enter the passphrase

Comment: yes. It executes the script and then exits. I recommend you to try the script syntax before trying in in xterm and ssh, just locally, like `python /srv/django/manage.py shell execfile('./myscript.py')` -- it has syntax errors.

Comment: Adding "-hold" to xterm will keep the window open, like `xterm -hold -e ...`

Comment: when you try to copy & paste the code in my last comment into bash, it will show the syntax errors. Not sure what it should actually do.

Comment: Make sure the file `myscript.py` is in your home directory on `server`. There is problem in django/python command and here I can't help more.